# MongoDb find opeartion on nested array having multiiple json object in it

Tags: arrays, json, mongodb

I'm having dataset in which json consists of array having multiple json in it.

The objects in the array have 4 keys, out of which 1 is missing in some of them.

I want to get the documents where all the objects in an array are missing the key.

e.g, From these following documents:

```
{"test":1,desc:[{"price":1,"abc":"def"},{"price":2,"ac":"def"}]}
{"test":1,desc:[{"price":1,"abc":"def"},{"ac":"def"}]}
{"test":1,desc:[{"abc":"def"},{"ac":"def"}]}
```

I want to match only the last document.

Thanks in advance..

Comment: Is it always the same field (`price`) that's missing? what are the 4 keys? aren't all document's suppose to match because all of them are missing the 4th key?

Comment: you need to specify your question: do you want to get all documents which have no key "price" at all in the array, or do you want to get all documents which have at least one object in array which has no key "price"

Comment: @TomSlabbaert yes the price is the only one thats missing in the other json ; also all the json shares the same structure. I am only concerned with the json whose array's json dont have price in any of its json , if its present in a single i have to neglect that.

Comment: @MBushveld yes i want to get all documents which has no key price "for all value in array"

Comment: @TomSlabbaert As from the above example ; the desc array : the four keyss i refer to is of type price , abc  ,..... the only thing i want is to retrieve that data for which "array.price" doesn't exist in the whole array (if it exists for any index of array i dont need that data). As in the last json i have shown there both json in desc doesn't have any nested key value pair for price.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use [$exists](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/exists/):

```
db.collection.find(
    {
        "desc.price": {$exists: false}
    }
)
```

And if you want for other fields as well:

```
db.collection.find(
    {
        $or: [
            {
                "desc.price": {$exists: false}
            },
            {
                "desc.abc": {$exists: false}
            },
            {
                "desc.ac": {$exists: false}
            }
        ]
    }
)
```

One thing to note is that an empty array, i.e `desc = []` will always be matched by this query. if you want to ensure there's atleast one object use this query:

```
db.collection.find(
    {
       $and: [
           {
               "desc.price": {$exists: false}
           },
           {
               "desc.0": {$exists: true}
           }
       ]
    }
)
```

Comment: Thanks for your response , this returns all the documents in which desc.price doesn't exists. What i want is , the desc is an array with multiple json embedded in it which consists of this price key value pair for some of their json. I want to get  only those documents whose array's json doesnt consist of price in any of their embedded json.

With this it also returns the json document which have both price in their desc and not in json  from  array.

Comment: I  am looking for a situation which checks:  desc[ ] .price == undefined or null for  all the json in that array ,, if any of the json from that array consists that price attribute will have to skip that document

Answer (score 0):

Achieved that, just made a script where i used an array to store the price thing and then used .every method for price to be  undefined , it returned me the desired result which i want.